# Best Practices for PIC18 Stack/Memory Management?

Tags: c, memory, stack

The limited stack size of budget PICs is a problem area and I have adjusted my code to accommodate this reality.  I currently adopt a rough paradigm of grouping closely related functions into a module and declaring all variables global static in the module (to reduce the amount of variables stored in the auto psect, and issues of mutability are only relevant in ISRs, which I account for.)  I don't do this because it is good practice, but the reality is you have a finite amount of space to allocate all local function vars that exist in an entire project.  In the embedded world of 8/16 bit chips, is this an appropriate method, provided I'm sure to take necessary precautions?  I also do things like allocate > 256 bytes of RAM for Ethernet (I know it should be 1500 as standard MTU, but we have a custom situation and very limited RAM) buffers and have to access that memory via pointers so I can avoid the semantics of memory banking.  Am I doing it wrong?  My app works, but I am 100% open to suggestions for improvement. [c]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this was asked 4 years ago but it still has not been properly answered. I believe what the OP is asking is is their approach to working around a limitation of the HiTech PICC18 C compiler valid and/or best practice. As mentioned in a later comment the limitation (a rather bad one and not well advertised by Hitech) is "the Hi-Tech compiler only allows up 256 bytes of auto variables". Actually the limitation is worse than that as it is a total of 256 bytes for local variables and parameters. The linker warning when this is exceeded is pretty cryptic too. Provided that functions are on different branches of the call tree then the compiler can overlap the variables to reuse the space. This means that you can effectively have more than 256 bytes. But note that the interrupt handler (or handlers if you use the priority scheme) has it's own call tree that shares the 256 byte local/param block.

**Locals**
The two solutions to reduce the space required for locals are: make the locals global or make them static. Making them static keeps the scope the same and provided the function is not called from interrupts is safe (rentrancy is not allowed by the compiler anyway). This is probably the preferred option. The drawback is that the compiler can not reuse those variable's locations to reduce overall memory consumption. Moving the variables to global scope allows reuse, but the reuse management must be managed by the programmer. Probably the best balance is to make simple variables static but to make large chunks of memory like string buffers global and carefully reuse them.

Be careful with initialisation.

```
foo()
{
 int myvar = 5;
}
```

must change to

```
foo()
{
 static int myvar;
 myvar = 5;
}
```

**Parameters** 
If you go around passing large lots of data down the call tree in parameters you will quickly run into the same 256 byte limitation. Your best option here may be to pass a pointer to a globally allocated struct/s of "options".Alternatively you can have global settings variables that are set by the top caller and read by callees down the tree. It really depends on the design of the software which approach is better.

I've struggled with the same issues as the OP and I think the best option in the long run is to move away from using the Hitech compiler. The optimisation decision the compiler writers took to allocate all locals/params in one block is only really appropriate for the very small ram size PICS. For large PICS you will run out of local/param far before you hit the ram size of the device. Then you have to start hacking your code around to fit the compiler which is perverse.

In summary... Yes your approach is valid. But do consider simply making locals static if that is appropriate as, in general, reducing the scope makes your code safer.

Comment: One point to watch with converting local to function scope static is be careful to check initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas the C18 compiler used some FSRs (pointers) to manage the data stack, it sounds like the new XC8 compiler from Microchip uses a compiled stack, so you should know exactly how much space is taken up by the stack at compile time.  You will also know exactly where each stack variable is stored.  I read all about this in the [XC8 user's guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/xc8-v1.20-manual.pdf) and it sounds great.  That feature should make this question be moot, assuming you are using XC8.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with compilers/linkers for chips with limited memory is that, as long as you don't use recursive functions and inform the compiler about that, then the compiler is very capable of determining the minimal amount of stack-space that is needed.
I have even seen compilers that give each variable with automatic storage a globally fixed address (no stack at all), where several variables got allocated to overlapping memory, as long as their lifetimes did not overlap.

The general advise when doing (speed or space) optimisations is: make measurements to prove that your optimisation actually has a positive effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are nearly out of memory, you have to count each byte of RAM. Using local variables (auto) allows to reuse the memory where you need it (local in the function). When you move the variables to global static address space, you give each variable a unique space. That's wast of address space.

The Microchip compiler allows that different variables share the same address. I don't have the docs at hand, but this can be done by pragma.

But what you need is a analysis of RAM requirements. When you see, that the stack cannot hold all variables but the auto variables would reduce the global memory use, you should consider to increase the stack size using startup code and the linker script.

Comment: We're using the Hi-Tech PICC18 Pro compiler. The differences between it and the Microchip C18 are many, but the important ones are that the Hi-Tech compiler only allows up 256 bytes of auto variables and this compiler doesn't have any linker scripts that I can edit (to my knowledge.)

Comment: OP is talking about stack/local space not ram in general.

Answer (score 0):

Best practive is to choose a hardware that fits the requirements.

There are microcontrollers around the cost only some dollars more, but save hundereds or thousand of dollars development costs. If this is a hobby development your effort may not count. But in real world you can often find hardware that is designed only with view of hardware costs.

Especially the PIC18 is not the best example for compact code, what also can be a problem with the flash memory.

Comment: This is not the first time I've heard this point made.  It is well taken, I will make a case to use AVR uCs for future projects and possibly IAR dev tools.  I do not control the funding and this project already has a substantial amount of firmware written for the current chips, changing uCs is not an option at this point.

Comment: @harper Commercial enterprises run by non-technical managers are exactly the ones pushing developers into using the smallest chip possible!

Comment: @Nate An AVR with RAM limitations suffers from the same problems as the PIC. While personal uP preferences are fine (and the AVR are fine chips) it is not ultimately an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you should also have a closer look at the C18 compiler user guide (if you were using this compiler).

You could decrease the stack dramatically by statically allocating local variables (overriding the auto keyword). Even better, you can use the overlay storage identifier, which allows different non-overlapping lifetimes variables to be placed at the same address, minimizing RAM. (C18 compiler must operate in Non-Extended mode).

Answer (score 0):

This migth sound obvious, but try not to use 16 bits variables on 8 bit precessors. 16 bits variables are fine and needed on bigger arquitectures, but in limited (8 bit) architectures a 16 bit aritmetic is a quick way for depleting both RAM and ROM memories in no time.

If you try to increment a 16 bits variable, the compiler would include a 16 bits increment library, that consumes in most cases a lot of space.

Also, try not to divide or multiply, as for some controllers they are software implemented.

Personally, I go alwais for `char` and when in need of a divide operation, use rotate rigth 'n' times to divide by 2 n times.

hope this helps!

Comment: Down voting as this just offers general advice and does not address the OP's main question.